# Why is this ruby code returning a blank page instead of filling it up with user names?

Tags: ruby, web-scraping, web-crawler

I want to collect the names of users in a particular group, called Nature, in the photo-sharing website Fotolog. This is my code:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mechanize'
require 'csv'

def getInitUser()
    agent1 = Mechanize.new

    number = 0
    while number<=500
        address = 'http://http://www.fotolog.com/nature/participants/#{number}/'
        logfile2 = File.new("Fotolog/Users.csv","a")

        tryConut = 0
        begin
            page = agent1.get(address)
        rescue
            tryConut=tryConut+1
            if tryConut<5
                retry
            end
            return
        end

        arrayUsers= []

        # search for the users
        page.search("a[class=img_border_radius").map do |opt| 

            link = opt.attributes['href'].text
            link = link.gsub("http://www.fotolog.com/","").gsub("/","")
            arrayUsers << link
            logfile2.print("#{link}\n")
        end
        number = number+100
    end
    return arrayUsers
end    

arrayUsers = getInitUser()
arrayUsers.each do |user|
    getFriend(user)
end
```

But the Users.csv file I am getting is empty. What's wrong here? I suspect it might have something to do with the "class" tag I am using. But from the inspect element, it seems to be the correct class, isn't it? I am just getting started with web crawling, so I apologise if this is a silly query.

[image]

Comment: Your selector is wrong. If you're trying to use an xpath, you have to use something like this: `page.search(".//a[@class='img_border_radius']")`. But I would just use a css selector:

```page.search("a .img_border_radius")
```

Or you could even use
```page.links_with(class: ".img_border_radius").map```...

Also I would `puts` instead of `print` (I don't even know that `print` is a correct way to write to a file), replacing `logfile2.print("#{link}\n")` with `logfile2.puts("#{link}")`

Another thing is you have to close the file after using it `logfile.close`.